# Write text file and open at same time

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to write text file from textbox on button's click event

after writing it I need to open same file

does not need to save that file while writing.

can anyone please give sample code?

**EDIT**

Actually you take me wrong ,I need to create temporary file , not in already existed file.. need to create , write and at same time it will be open to read.. is it possible ?

Comment: Did you try? If so, show the exact problem you have.

Comment: Paste you code here. What have you tried ?

Comment: You want to write without saving? I don't know what you're on about.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Actually you take me wrong ,I need to create temporary file , not in already existed file.. need to create , write and at same time it will be open to read.. is it possible ?

Comment: @sphair please check my comments

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/ and then improve the question taking into account these suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
FileStream currentFileStream = null;//EDIT
string tempFilePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\TEMP.txt";

if (!File.Exists(tempFilePath))
{
    currentFileStream = File.Create(tempFilePath);//creates temp text file
    currentFileStream.Close();//frees the file for editing/reading
}//if file does not already exist

File.WriteAllText(tempFilePath, textbox1.Text);//overwrites all text in temp file

//Inside your exit function:
if(File.Exists(tempFilePath)) File.Delete(tempFilePath);//delete temp file
```

Comment: get error 'System.IO.FileStream' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Comment: Sorry, I had written the code more or less off the top of my head, should work now (just had to change currentFileStream to initialise to null)

Answer (score 0):

StreamWriter writes text files. It enables easy and efficient text output. It is best placed in a using-statement to ensure it is removed from memory when no longer needed. It provides several constructors and many methods.

[Click Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamwriter)

Process.Start(file)

Answer (score 0):

What do you need to do after you open the file again?

Real simply, you can write your text to the file with

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("path",textbox1.Text);
```

And you can open the file with:

```
system.IO.File.Open() // and the other variants .OpenText, OpenWrite
```

Comment: And there is also [System.IO.File.ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx) which makes the read task very easy.

Comment: Actually you take me wrong ,I need to create temporary file , not in already existed file.. need to create , write and at same time it will be open to read.. is it possible ?

Comment: Did you read the documentation of File.WriteAllText? And: if you want to create a temporary file, then you should use [`System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename).